# What does char '|' mean in Linux command

Tags: shell

In example:

`lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`

How do I "read" that command? I have tried to search anywhere, and found nothing explained those.

Comment: Is this what you seek for: https://superuser.com/questions/178796/understanding-how-inputs-are-sent-to-pipes-in-bash

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score -1):

This PIPE operator is very useful where the output of the first command acts as an input to the second command. For example, pipeline the output of `ls -l` to ‘less‘ and see the output of the command.